# How would you translate "hard" in "squeeze my hand as hard as you can"?

Tags: translation

Odd question, perhaps, but I'm stumped.  I know that to say 'as fast as you can' you can say 尽可能快, but what about for other adjectives?

For example, if you were to say 'Squeeze my hand as hard as you can," how would that be translated properly into Chinese?

Comment: Verbatim 捏我的手吧，你能用多大力，就用多大力。After leaning western etiquette a simple hand shake becomes a squeezing contest.

Comment: My personal interpreter and erstwhile boss says: 'as hard as you can' = '尽用全力[do whatever]‘

Answer (score 2):

The adverb/adjective you're looking for is '紧' (tight), which is commonly used for squeezing, seizing or grabbing something especially hands.

'Squeeze my hand as hard as you can' can be translated into '抓住我的手，越紧越好' or '尽可能紧地抓住我的手'.

Comment: +1, I think it also depends on *why* it's being said: if in a hospital, "please squeeze my hand as hard as you can" as a test is quite different from say, in a novel "she squeezed my hand as hard as she could". In either case, your first example feels like it covers the hospital, and your second the novel.

Answer (score 1):

尽你所能把我手握紧。 'Squeeze my hand as hard as you can。‘

Comment: iciba 翻译：握紧我的手尽你所能

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of `squeeze` you mean.

If you mean `抓`, you can say `抓好我的手，越紧越好！`

If you mean `捏`, you can say `捏住我的手，越紧越好！`

We seldom say `尽可能地抓住` ... it's very weird in daily speaking Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

`吃奶劲儿` is sometimes used in Beijing. It may sound funny, but `吃奶` is `drinking milk`, right? Babies used a lot of strength to suck on the breast to get their milk, and so this is used to convey the meaning of substantial strength. So you could say `用吃奶劲儿抓我的手`.

Answer (score 0):

用最大的劲握住我的手。
squeeze my hand： 握住我的手
as hard as you can：最大的劲

Answer (score 0):

Squeeze my hand as hard as you can. I have a more oral way to say this in Mandarin， and that is  尽可能的攥紧我的手。
Squeeze my hand should be translated into"攥紧我的手”
" hard" in this sentence shouldn't be translated directly, but be translated with the phrase" as hard as" as a whole.

I.e.as soon as possible should be translated into"尽可能快”

Answer (score 0):

可以翻译成：使出全身的劲捏我的手
hard : 就是用力的意思